# Export only a part of the database for migration

Tags: database, export

I have to migrate a very large WordPress Installation, and the majority of the data is (too) old and not needed.

I was looking for a possibility or plugin to export only a part of the database: only posts from 2019, but all pages.

An old blog entry suggests a plugin called "Advanced Exporter", but I could not find it: https://managewp.com/blog/wordpress-migrating-content-and-media.

Is there a plugin or other solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind exporting pages and posts separately, you can use the default WordPress export tool to achieve that.

On the Export screen you can set the tool to export only posts. Then add a suitable date filter. After that do another export, but this time set the tool to export only pages.

You can read more about the default export tool on the codex, https://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen

I think majority of the backup/export plugins only let you choose which database tables are backedup/exported instead of letting you do such conditional/partial export.